# What is the .Net 2.0 equivalent of xElement.Parse (string)

Tags: c#, xml, .net-2.0

I have code in C# .Net 4.0 that I need to work on computer functioning with the .Net 2.0 framework. Basically, what it does is read lines of data from a server. A line looks something like this:

```
<REC CNT="5275" TIME="-66520.287" TIME_TICK="0" FPOGX="0.00000" FPOGY="0.00000" FPOGS="0.000" FPOGD="0.000" FPOGID="0"/>
```

I took these lines and added it to an XML document using the XElement.Parse function. Following disconnection, the data was saved.

```
XElement xmlDoc = new XElement("Data");

do
    //dataLine is a string obtained each iteration by reading from a network stream
    XElement xmlDataLine = XElement.Parse(dataLine);
    xmlDoc.Add(xmlDataLine)
while (!stopClient)

xmlDoc.Save(fileName)
```

How can I do this in .Net 2.0?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are best off using `XmlDocument`;

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
XmlElement root = (XmlElement)doc.AppendChild(doc.CreateElement("Data"));

do {
    string dataLine = ...;
    using(XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(
        new StringReader(dataLine)))
    {
        root.AppendChild(doc.ReadNode(reader));
    }
} while (!stopClient);
doc.Save(target);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`XmlDocument.LoadXml`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldocument.loadxml.aspx), but then you'd need to import the root element into the target document:

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.LoadXml(xmlDataLine);
XmlNode imported = xmlDoc.ImportNode(doc.DocumentElement, true);
xmlDoc.DocumentElement.AppendChild(imported);
```